# LESS: watch() mode solve problems with @import?

Tags: less, browser-cache, watch

I have this problem with a LESS project. It's first time that I try this new language...

I'm using **less.js** library to parse `.less` file in real time.

I created many `.less` files with a `main.less` that `@import` others. Today I experienced some strange behaviour:

- Some edits on a secondary .less file seems to be completely ignored.
- On another PC the same website (I edit my files directly on an ftp folder) has previous modifications, so they were correct!
- Coming back to original PC, again, modifications are ignored.

I thought about *cache* problems but even empting cache, problem remains....

Here on SO I found a possible solution concerning `watch()` mode... I tried adding **`#!watch`** at the end of the URL as suggested in official documentation and it seems running correctly. (see [lesscss import and watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893647/lesscss-import-and-watch))

So, can you explain me why there is this problem (apparently related only to secondary files, not on the `main.less`) and what is the exact role of `watch()` mode?

Thank you,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cached files are not stored in the browser cache but in browser's local Storage. Empty your cache did not clean these files.

Before running less.js you will have the opportunity to setup a global javascript object with settings. The most important setting in this case seems `env` set it to `development` this will prevent caching of your LESS files. Running .watch will do the same. See also: [using Sass/Less and Live Css editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476413/using-sass-less-and-live-css-editing/2048173)